# How to get values out of JSON string array

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, json, stringify

I am passing the following array via jQuery ajax and JSON stringify...

```
"sessionsArray":[{"eventNum":"15200","title":"Integrity"},{"eventNum":"15210","title":"Estate and Probate"}]
```

to a c#/.NET web service.  I need to loop over and extract the values but I'm having fuzzy brain today and cannot get the syntax correct.  Help please?

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    public string saveRegistration(Dictionary <string, string> sessionsArray)

List<string[]> eventsList = new List<string[]>();

foreach (var eventItem in sessionsArray)
{
    eventsList.Add(new[] { eventItem.Key, eventItem.Value });
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Deserialize JSON with C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7895105/deserialize-json-with-c-sharp)

Comment: Sorry, the only thing the same is the JSON string.  I still don't see how to handle when the value is passed into my web service.  I see some suggest using Dictionary, others something else.  No one seems to agree.

Comment: Can you post your Javascript code please.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work.

```
Dictionary <string, string>[] sessionsArray
```

Comment: instead of just giving one liner as answer, include description also?

Answer (score 0):

I guess I would define a model first for my objects like the following:

```
public class SessionsArray
{
 public string eventNum { get; set; }
 public string title { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
  public List<SessionsArray> sessionsArray { get; set; }
}
```

Then I would parse the json with JSON.NET:

```
string json = "{'sessionsArray':[{'eventNum':'15200','title':'Integrity'},{'eventNum':'15210','title':'Estate and Probate'}]}";
var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Newtonsoft.Json as follow :

var jsonData = JObject.Parse(sessionArray);
Then you have JObject. You can cast this to JArray and you can use for loop to get data.

```
for(int i = 0 ; i<(JArray)jsonData.Count;i++)
{
var data = jsonData[i];
}
```